# Why react router redirect immediately without waiting for inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Below is `App.tsx`

```
function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    (
      async () => {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/user', {
          headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
          credentials: 'include',
        });
        const content = await response.json();
        setName(content.name);
      }
    )();
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Nav name={name} setName={setName}/>
        <main className="form-signin">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={() => <Home name={name}/>}/>
            <Route path="/login" element={() => <Login setName={setName}/>}/>
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>
          </Routes>
        </main>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Below is `Login.tsx`

```
const Login = (props: {setName: (name: string) => void }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  const submit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password
      })
    });
    const content = await response.json();
    setRedirect(true);
    props.setName(content.name);
  }

  if (redirect) {
    return <Navigate to='/'/>
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submit}>
      <h1 className="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>
      <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required
        onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required
        onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button className="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Below is `Nav.tsx`

```
    const Nav = (props: {name: string, setName: (name: string) => void}) => {
        const logout = async () => {
            await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/logout', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                credentials: 'include',
            });
            props.setName('');
        }

        let menu;
        // console.log(props.name);
        if (props.name === '') {
            menu = (
                <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                    <li className="nav-item active">
                        <Link to="/login" className="nav-link">Login</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item active">
                        <Link to="/register" className="nav-link">Register</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            )
        } else {
            menu = (
                <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                    <li className="nav-item active">
                        <Link to="/login" className="nav-link" onClick={logout}>Logout</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            )
        }

        return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">Home</Link>
                    <div>
                        {menu}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        );
    };
```

When I try to load the page, either `Home` or `Login` I get `401 (Unauthorized)`.

Update:
Below is the code of `Home.tsx`

```
    import React from "react";

    const Home = (props: {name: string}) => {
        return (
            <div>
                {props.name ? 'Hi ' + props.name : 'you are not logged in'}
            </div>
        );
    }

    export default Home;
```

Comment: Is it possibly because the routes rendering `Home` and `Login` are syntactically incorrect? the `element` prop takes only a `ReactElement`, not a function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I add the code rendering `Home`. It take a function with a parameter. Similar for `Login`. Source code can be found in the link below https://github.com/scalablescripts/react-auth/tree/main/src

Comment: No, I was referring to the `Route` components rendering `Home` and `Login`. `Route` component's `element` prop doesn't take functions that render JSX. `element={() => <Home name={name}/>}` isn't valid, it should be `element={<Home name={name}/>}`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you didn't get the maximum update depth exceeded error of `useEffect` call.

you have to change it to this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (
      async () => {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/user', {
          headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
          credentials: 'include',
        });
        const content = await response.json();
        setName(content.name);
      }
    )();
  }, []); //<= add empty dependency here so you call the backend once per load
```

another problem is that you didn't set the `email` and `password` values to their correspondent inputs:

```
<input value={email} type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required
        onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
<input value={password} type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required
        onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did as what you said, but problem remains. 401 unauthorized. The html components in Longin.tsx does not show up.

Comment: @MiloLu put all of your components in codesandbox.io and share the link to it, so we could help you better

Comment: the source code is here, if you are interested, https://github.com/scalablescripts/react-auth

Comment: I modified the part related to router, as it is not compatible with the latest version of react